# Sequelize "ER_TABLE_EXISTS_ERROR" "errno: 1050" when trying to create many-to-one associations

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create a one question survey system. I have `Survey`, `SurveyResult` and `User` models. `Survey` is for creating surveys and `SurveyResult` is for storing user answers. A `SurveyResult` can have one user and survey. `Survey` and `User` can have survey results more than once. When I try make these associations like:

```
SurveyResult.belongsTo(User,{foreigney: 'userId'})
SurveyResult.belongsTo(Survey,{foreigney: 'surveyId'})
```

I'm getting a `"Table './retronet/survey@002dresults' already exists"` error.

These are my Models:

### User

```
const sequelize = require('../utility/database')
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const Role = require('./role')

const User = sequelize.define('users',{
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    username: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    roleId : {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
            model: Role,
            key: 'id'
        },
        defaultValue: 4294
    }
},
{
    initialAutoIncrement: 10423204895734
})

module.exports = User
```

### Survey

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = require('../utility/database')

const Survey = sequelize.define('surveys',{
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    options: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT,
        allowNull: false
    },
    multipleSelect: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
    
},
{
    initialAutoIncrement: 1232432,
    timestamps: false
}
)

module.exports = Survey
```

### SurveyResult

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const sequelize = require('../utility/database')
const Survey = require('./survey')
const User = require('./user')

const SurveyResult = sequelize.define('survey-results',{
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    answer: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    surveyId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
            model: Survey,
            key: 'id'
        },
        allowNull: false
    },
    userId: {
        type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
        references: {
            model: User,
            key: 'id'
        },
        allowNull: false
    },
},
{
    initialAutoIncrement: 423420,
    timestamps: false
}
)

module.exports = SurveyResult
```

How can I solve it and is there a better way to do that?

Comment: When do you get the error? You have typos in the foreignKey property in the object you're passing into belongsTo() association methods. You also likely need to set up belongsToMany() associations for User and Survey in order to get your desired functionality.

Comment: I corrected the typos and tried using belongsToMany() but still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you share when the 'table already exists' error is being thrown? Are you using sequelize.sync() or is this happening when running migrations? That error being thrown with a file path like that looks very unfamiliar to me. Feels like there is probably some structural issue with the code rather than a simple syntax error. The code for these models seems fine.

Comment: I'm using sequelize.sync() method.

Comment: I take it that you are getting this 'Table already exists' error when starting your server, in that case? You can try passing { force: true } into the .sync() method. That will drop your tables and rebuild them with the attributes from your models. As I mentioned in the previous comment, it seems to me that your issue stems from somewhere other than the code in these models, though.

Comment: I'm already using {force: true} but it doesn't matter.